# maven does not copy dependencies

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, webserver, m2eclipse

I have Dynamic Web Application project in eclipse that was converted to maven project.
Problem is that all dependencies are copied to:

`<project>/target/<project>-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib`

not `<project>/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib`

so when I run application from eclipse, there are no libs from maven and I get some errors.
I assume that application started from eclipse i.e on tomcat server gets it source from `<project>/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [m2e](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) (Maven Plugin for Eclipse). It automatically adds Maven dependencies to the classpath, so you don´t need them in /WEB-INF/lib while running from Eclipse.

Comment: So the right question is "why m2e is not adding the dependencies to the classpath" :) Did you converted Eclipse configuration do Maven? You didn´t say the version of Eclipse you are using, but try Right click in the project -> Configure -> Convert do Maven Project